# Idiom/phrase for acting surprisingly passive

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'd be greatly appreciative of an idiom/phrase that depicts a subject (e.g. a governmental organisation) that acts surprisingly passive in relation to a given situation.

Context:
The governmental organisation seem to be just observing without taking any concrete actions, while you would expect them to take action since it should be of vital importance to them.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: [Idiomatic expression meaning to not reveal emotions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284628/idiomatic-expression-meaning-to-not-reveal-emotions/284703#284703).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do you call a person that won’t act?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180283/what-do-you-call-a-person-that-won-t-act) (==> apathetic, spectator, the bystander effect ...)

Comment: Thank you @EdwinAshworth, I can definitely use one of those suggestions.